# Routing error using Wagtail v2 with Django v1.11

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Can't seem to find anything on this so far, I'm guessing I have something misconfigured somewhere.

I have a pre-existing Django app and am trying to use Wagtail to add a blog in. I have installed as per the instructions and I can access the default landing page so it seems to be installed however I'm stuck with the below error when attempting to access the admin for it and am not sure how to proceed. Guessing its something to do with not defining namespaces somewhere, the Wagtail docs say that its compatible with Django v1.11 but their integration documentation is for Django v2 specifically and is using re_path etc.

```
'wagtailadmin_api_v1' is not a registered namespace
```

My main project urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
    url(r'^taggit_autosuggest/', include('taggit_autosuggest.urls')),
    url(r'^autocomplete/', include(ac_urls, namespace='ac')),
    url(r'^', include('website.urls', namespace='website')),
]
```

My blog app's urls.py (which is fresh from a "python manage.py startapp blog")

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.documents import urls as wagtaildocs_urls
from wagtail.core import urls as wagtail_urls

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^cms/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),
    url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),
]
```

When I attempt to access localhost:8000/blog/ I get the default wagtail landing page, if I go to localhost:8000/blog/cms/ I get the above error though. If I go to localhost:8000/blog/documents/ I get a 404 as well.

Not sure where I'm going wrong, have tried using a version of wagtail that still used the Django v1.11 way of routing in urls.py but I got the same error!

Comment: what if you try `localhost:8000/blog/cms/` and `localhost:8000/blog/documents/`?

Comment: Apologies, that is what I meant to write in the above!